# Is using locales like "de-US" or "fr-US" acceptable/valid?

Tags: php, localization, locale

In my application I would allow users in the United States to see pages in German or French when they switch the language. So the region is *US* and the language is *de* or *fr*, what should lead to a constructed locale of *de-US* or *fr-US*. That means, French gets displayed, but e.g. the format of dates corresponds to *US*. What is what I would like achieve.

Are those locales valid? I saw [this list](http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/iso3166.html#US) for 'valid' US locales:

> ```
> Cherokee (United States) (chr-US)
> English (United States) (en-US)
> English (United States, Computer) (en-US-POSIX)
> Spanish (United States) (es-US)
> Hawaiian (United States) (haw-US)
> Lakota (United States) (lkt-US)
> ```

Does that mean *de-US* is not valid and must not be used or created?

I'm aware with such locales I would get only the general fr language, not *br-FR*. That would be okay for me.

Class [Locale](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) doesn't seem to have a problem with such locales.

Comment: Athough the production of the tags is valid, the authoritative source is http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry To understand language tagging in general, this is a good reference source from the W3C https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/